# Optimising test re-test reliability through randomly generating hypothetical repeated trials

Tags: monte-carlo, random-generation, reliability

I have had a look around the forum, and despite some similar questions on measurement error, no one appears to have asked this question specifically.

I have developed a test where a small group of participants $(n = 40)$ have undertaken three trials each of the test in total. See the two attached figures for an example Bland Altman plot representation of score comparisons for both (a) Trial 1 (on the x axis) vs Trial 2 (change in performance on y axis) and (b) Trial 2 vs Trial 3, respectively. Whilst in the second figure, the Trial 3 scores are much more similar to the Trial 2 scores as opposed to those in the first figure, on the whole a learning effect still seems to exist, with the majority of participants producing higher scores in the subsequent testing trial.

[image]

[image]

So, as these figures show (along with the mean difference and limit of agreement values—not shown here), there appears to be on the whole a learning effect for undertaking repeated trials of the test, that may not ‘stabilise’ even after having undertaken three trials in total (not totally unexpected, however, given the complex requirements of the test).
 
Unfortunately, collecting further data (i.e. trials 4, 5, 6 etc.) is not feasible in this instance.

Therefore, my question relates to whether there is an approach that could be used to determine how many trials would be needed in order to reach ‘acceptable’:

- mean change (improvements or decrement) when compared to the preceding trial and
- reliability indices (i.e. 95% limits of agreement or ICC’s).

I understand the subjectivity in determining what ‘acceptable’ values means in this context; however, my question is around the methodology.

My thoughts at this stage—could Monte Carlo simulations be used to generate random scores for a hypothetical Trial 4 (and perhaps trial 5) based on scores reported by the initial cohort for trials 1–3 (or the trends from these trials)? This would first allow identification of when the familiarisation/learning effect from undertaking repeated trials is reduced or plateaus/stabilises (i.e. trial 4, 5 or otherwise). Second, it may also allow identification of when and if ‘acceptable’ reliability can be achieved (i.e. ICC’s of $>$ 0.80, narrower 95% limits of agreement) based on the results discovered thus far.